# Blender 2.8 - Multiple View Layers

Tags: viewlayers

is it possible to add new ViewLayers to current beta version, or it is work in progress? I am looking for a way to render two objects on two separate viewlayers with different compositing nodes on each and then merge them together.
I have been looking around but cannot find a definite answer how to do it, or if it is even possible.

I am using Cycles and Eevee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

View layers, that previously are been here:

[image]

Now moved in top right corner:

[image]

This animatable checks

[image]

Now presented it view layer settings:

[image]

Per layer settings for exclude, holdout and indirect only, that previously are been here:

[image]

now can be setup in context menu:

[image]

You need to know that EEVEE doesn't supports holdout and indirect only at current time.

Comment: Thank you, spent so much time looking for it yesterday and google gave me no definite answer <3

Comment: I guess this new system of excluding/masking is not animateable, right? Also, how to understand that layer is used as Holdout: some icon is greyed or something else?

Comment: @SergeL at current time, it needs some works, yes

Comment: @SergeL don't forget that it is a beta-version of software, most of commercial software doesn't posted in alpha state at all

Comment: With such major update it is a right way to do it, makes transition to new version much easier